# Is there a workaround for uploading an HTML file with JavaScript to a homepage editor that only accepts HTML, no JavaScript can be in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been tasked with updating a school library's homepage on a library management system called Destiny. I can only paste the HTML I've written into a text box and save it. I was unaware it would not accept JavaScript until I went to upload it:
[javascript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mahQG.png)

The main focal points of the website were a photo carousel and a carousel from a vendor which shows the digital magazines currently available in the school collection, both of which need JavaScript.

Is there anyway to access the JavaScript in my HTML file without having the script tags? Is there a workaround I can do?

Comment: Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

It's technically possible to execute scripts without a `<script>` tag. Whether it will work here will depend on how well that library sanitizes the HTML. As a hack, you might be able to insert an `<img>` with a malformed `src`, but an `onerror` handler:

```html
<img src onerror="console.log('insert your script here');">
```

and put all the code inside the `onerror`.

If the page doesn't have a strict [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), the best approach would probably be to then host a standalone `.js` file on a server (either on this one, if you're able to, or somewhere else), and then dynamically inject it, so you don't have to type out everything inside the handler.

```
<img
  src
 onerror="document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='some-src';"
>
```

But even if the system happens to accept this (it may not - if it doesn't, that means it's more secure!), you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: "But you probably shouldn't do this" ....... as if anyone who codes will take that advice on board ...... :)